# Compare 2 arrays of objects by 2 different keys. And make one nested object which contains parent and child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, lodash

I have problem with comparing 2 arrays of objects. I was searching lodash documentation, but I was not able to find proper method.
The thing is that I need to compare objects by different keys.

```
private parentArray: {}[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'A' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'B' },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'C' },
    { Id: 4, Name: 'D' }
  ];

private childArray: {}[] = [
    { Id: 2, parentId: 2, Name: 'a' },
    { Id: 3, parentId: 2, Name: 'b' },
    { Id: 4, parentId: 4, Name: 'c' },
    { Id: 5, parentId: 4, Name: 'd' }
  ];
```

I need to make a new array of nested objects where 'parentId' will be matched with 'Id' of parent which will look like that:

```
private newArray = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'A', Children: [] },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'B',
      Children: [
        { Id: 2, parentId: 2, Name: 'a' },
        { Id: 3, parentId: 2, Name: 'b' }
      ]
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: 'C',
      Children: []
    },
    {
      Id: 4,
      Name: 'D',
      Children: [
        { Id: 4, parentId: 4, Name: 'c' },
        { Id: 5, parentId: 4, Name: 'd' }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I was using '.intersectionWith([arrays], [comparator])' and '.isMatchWith(object, source, [customizer])' but it did not give me what I need.
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably

```
const newArray = parentArray.map(
    p => ({ ...p, Children: childArray.filter(c => c.parentId === p.Id) })
)
```

which results in the output you are looking for.  Note that this is not necessarily the best performing algorithm in the case where `parentArray` and `childArray` are large, since we are looping over the entire `childArray` for every element in `parentArray` (so if `childArray` is length  and `parentArray` is length  then this algorithm is *O*(×)).

If such performance matters then you can do it by iterating over each element in `childArray` and `parentArray` once (which is *O*(+) assuming hash lookups are *O*(1)), like this:

```
type Parent = typeof parentArray[number];
type Child = typeof childArray[number];
interface New extends Parent {
    Children: Child[];
}

const newArray: New[] = [];
const parentLookup: Record<number, New> = {};    
for (const p of parentArray) {
    const n = { ...p, Children: [] };
    newArray.push(n)
    parentLookup[p.Id] = n;
}
for (const c of childArray) {
    parentLookup[c.parentId]?.Children.push(c);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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-awx1vc6YD0u3XjdmG+a5ZapbbgyKPLSYBRiAAZADyAHF3Cny93mdYmyP2Zy9bzbkm1SmQ5Jw06s6anc3Ffvi8fS53A92r43+17n83rQcO+fG1nDC1d0UiND83Wbf0f20U8uHXAD92bOM70PEtU3IM84IHatrx3WkC2Q-kH1iJ83XrID33sIcfVw1sfwbctMwHXtnwowcgObMdanEaCKHEdwYHJUlJjAYwIEQYAUAYN4AAVvjeEAkG2MAJIAWQQKAviQCBwwOKBcDgSTpJA2AiD0gyQDeVZMEJYgwAAVz4SpvgmWozMkxMVjciyAUPdZbIcpykBcmRgnQOSEAkngFhgFAAA8vjARhtKM-o-3te8wFYRMhRJGRuKRWpplgfF1lYbgFiFFYcoOIqrLnEAQAAazsuBWAAJRQUAkEYAAeezHO+ZQFhOIgaHEXLqHkpBTlquAYG8j11lhBj9VqsAVnOS5rhQtATwkCb7RKwkgTsiBAjxREKzqhrmrgYhISYfiiDAA6g1qKaZpRAJ5ssx5wiWtL9Q9eqmpa4hAX7dwAH4Ngyk6zt+YkoMKlE0QxLFcSOqJYRgUlSRgCBjF4yYgA)

Answer (score 1):

```js
type Parent = {
    Id: number,
    Name: string,
}

type Child = Parent & {
    parentId: number;
}

type ParentAndChildren = {
    Children: Child[]
} & Parent


const parents: Parent[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'A' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'B' },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'C' },
    { Id: 4, Name: 'D' }
  ];

const children: Child[] = [
    { Id: 2, parentId: 2, Name: 'a' },
    { Id: 3, parentId: 2, Name: 'b' },
    { Id: 4, parentId: 4, Name: 'c' },
    { Id: 5, parentId: 4, Name: 'd' }
  ];

const output = parents.map((p: Parent): ParentAndChildren => {
    return {
        Id: p.Id,
        Name: p.Name,
        Children: children.filter((c) => p.Id === c.parentId),
    }
})

console.log(output);
```